# View updating after $http.get but not ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using `$http.get` to return a `JSON array`. If I simply echo the array it prints in the view fine. However, my `ng-repeat` container does not update.

To further confuse, I have a filter on the data which, when I filter for filename e.g. beginning with the number 1, suddenly they all appear (that match the filter anyway as they should).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
capApp.controller('myUploadedPhotos', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://myurl.com/ajax/myUploadedPhotos.php")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.photos = response;
    });
});

<div ng-controller="myUploadedPhotos" class="container">
  <h1>Hey {{photos}}</h1> <!-- this prints the array to the screen perfectly -->

<div class="photo" ng-repeat="x in photos | filter: { filename: nameFilter } | orderBy: order">
  // this doesn't show any images until I filter
  <img ng-src="/uploads/{{ x.filename }}" />
</div>
```

No errors anywhere by the way.

Any ideas how I could fix this?

**UPDATE**

It's clearly something to do with the filter, when I remove it, all works ok and images show.

This is the filter field:

```
<div>Filename: <input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" /></div>
```

Should I be somehow setting this to "" on init?

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Is your `filter` blocking the new results? Are you positive the response is an array.

Comment: I assume your objects have a `filename` property, correct?

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah, as I said, when I actually use the filter it works ok - they all start with number 1, as soon as I type that they all show - weird

Comment: Hmm, yeah, the filter may have to be initialized... just do a `$scope.nameFilter = ""` at the top of your controller. :\

Comment: Yeah, that's done it mate, thank you. That's a bad way to work if I have to initialise what should be null or empty by default - thanks again - if you want to add it as an answer I'll gladly accept.